# How to enter item from datatable into textbox

Tags: c#, sql, forms

First C# form app for me. I can write it in POSH, but I'm trying to graduate and understand C#. I know I have a long way to go, but if someone could help explain this, I would be grateful.

I have a simple SQL table with the following: CLIENT, INPATH, OUTPATH, LIMITERS (PK)
LIMITERS have Unique Values
For each CLIENT, INPATH and OUTPATH are the same.
I am trying to create a form that does the following:

Display a listbox with distinct CLIENT -Working

--- The rest is not working ---

On ListBox Click:

Fill TextBox with INPATH for selected CLIENT

Fill TextBox with OUTPATH for selected CLIENT

Fill ListBox with LIMITERS for selected CLIENT

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;




namespace DSI_SFTP_FrontEnd
{
    public partial class ClientMain : Form
    {
        private SqlDbConnect con;
       

        public ClientMain()

        {
            InitializeComponent();
            con = new SqlDbConnect();
            con.SqlQuery("Select Distinct CLIENT from Client_Inf");
            clientListBoxValues.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow dr in con.QueryEx().Rows)
            {
                clientListBoxValues.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                
            }
            


        }

        private void clientListBoxValues_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = clientListBoxValues.GetItemText(clientListBoxValues.SelectedItem);
            if (text != null)


            {
                InitializeComponent();

                string sql = $"Select INPATH, OUTPATH, LIMITERS from Client_Inf where CLIENT = '{text}'";

                con = new SqlDbConnect();
                con.SqlQuery(sql);
                DataTable dataTable = con.QueryEx();

                {
                    inPathTextBoxValue.Text = dataTable.Rows[0]["INPATH"].ToString();
                    outPathTextBoxValue.Text = dataTable.Rows[0]["OUTPATH"].ToString();
                }
                foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    limitersListBoxValues.Items.Add(dr[2].ToString());
                }

                
                
            }

        }

        private void createNewbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NewClientForm frm = new NewClientForm();
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

SqlDbConnect.cs

```
using System.Data;

namespace DSI_SFTP_FrontEnd
{
    public class SqlDbConnect
    {
        private SqlConnection _con;
        public SqlCommand _cmd;
        private SqlDataAdapter _da;    
        private DataTable _dt;

        public SqlDbConnect()
        { 
        _con=new SqlConnection("Server=<SERVER>;Database=<DB>;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;");   
            _con.Open();
        }

        public void SqlQuery(string queryText) 
        {
            _cmd= new SqlCommand(queryText, _con);
        }

        public DataTable QueryEx() 
        {
            _da = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
            _dt= new DataTable();
            _da.Fill(_dt);
            return _dt;
        }


        public void NonQueryEx() 
        {
            _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens? Also consider [debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) your method. It allows to you inspect e.g., the `text` variable to see whether it contains the expected value. If you get an exception: On which code line? What is the message text? What is `SqlDbConnect`? Which library are you using? Consider using [Dapper](https://www.learndapper.com/) instead.

Comment: Ok.. With a little digging prompted by Olivier's comment:
It looks like I'm getting returns to the textboxes, but it just isn't displaying in the form.

I think I need to find a way to return the textboxvalue from sub-block "private void clientListBoxValues_SelectedIndexChanged"

to parent block "public partial class ClientMain : Form"

Also: SqlDbConnect is my SQL connection class

Comment: If you're going to use datatables, you might as well leverage the facilities that will make VS write all this code for you and more

Comment: Thanks Caius, but that really doesn't help me here.
The data table is visible and the values can be assigned to and viewable in a variable "string <var>". For some reason though, I can't assign to a textbox, listbox, or combo.
TextBoxValue always shows Text=""

Comment: I ask about `SqlDbConnect`, because the standard connection class is `SqlConnection` from the namespace `System.Data.SqlClient`. I still don't know where `SqlDbConnect` comes from. If `in-` and `outPathTextBoxValue` are TextBoxes, then these are class fields and their `Text` property can be set from `clientListBoxValues_SelectedIndexChanged` without returning something to a parent block. Is there another code deleting the TextBoxes interfering with this code?

Comment: Thank you Olivier.
I posted the **SqlDbConnect** code with an edit.
I think I'm missing something with **clientListBoxValues_SelectedIndexChanged**.
As you can see, I'm attempting to modify the value with the following statement:
`inPathTextBoxValue.Text = dataTable.Rows[0]["INPATH"].ToString();` I created the textboxes in the form and only modified the names. The names are unique in the solution and have no other assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `InitializeComponent()` in `clientListBoxValues_SelectedIndexChanged`. `InitializeComponent()` creates the controls, .i.e., the TextBoxes and ListBoxes, etc. The effect is that you are creating another set of those controls every time the selected index of the ListBox changes.

`InitializeComponent()` must be called once in the constructor `ClientMain()` and nowhere else!